# DirectX 12 and C++ CLI : Cannot use IID_PPV_ARGS

Tags: c++, pointers, command-line-interface, directx

For a given function as follow :

> HRESULT D3D12CreateDevice(
>         IUnknown          *pAdapter,
>         D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL MinimumFeatureLevel,
>         REFIID            riid,
>         void              **ppDevice
>       );

The native C++ way of using it is :

```
ID3D12Device* d3d12Device; 
D3D12CreateDevice(adapter, featureLevel, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3d12Device));
```

The problem is that I cannot use IID_PPV_ARGS in a /CLI project because there is some kind of inaccessible macro in managed code.

So I try to do things as I used to do them with DirectX 11 & C++ CLI, as follow :

```
ID3D12Device* d3d12Device; 
D3D12CreateDevice(adapter, featureLevel, __uuidof(ID3D12Device), (void**)&d3d12Device);
```

It doesn't produce any compiler error but DX object creation always fails.. It used to work with DX 11 but not any more with DX12.

Someone could tell me how I am supposed to initialize DX12 object under C++ CLI please ?

Thank a lot.

**EDIT 1**

D3D12CreateDevice work with the following syntax (I was doing something wrong) :

```
ID3D12Device* d3d12Device; 
D3D12CreateDevice(adapter, featureLevel, __uuidof(ID3D12Device), (void**)&d3d12Device);
```

But I can't get a correct syntax for CreateCommandQueue.

> HRESULT CreateCommandQueue(   const D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC *pDesc,
>   REFIID                         riid,   void                       **ppCommandQueue );

This syntax give a cast error :

```
_d3d12Device->CreateCommandQueue(&queueDesc, IID_ID3D12CommandQueue, (void**)&_commandQueue)
```

C2440   'cast de type' : unable to convert 'cli::interior_ptr' into 'void **'

Comment: If you don't get a valid `d3d12Device` pointer, you should check values returned by `D3D12CreateDevice` call, and your another option is to enable debug layer and watch the debug output.

Comment: You need to check return value of `D3D12CreateDevice` to figure out whether returned pointer is valid (not other way around!). Also there is no need to use non-standard `__uuidof` operator, you can just supply value directly, for example `IID_ID3D12Device` .

Comment: I didn't know about IID_***** thank. I took the wrong exemple with D3D12CreateDevice cause it actually work with my second syntax. I had probably a problem elsewhere. But for something like ID3D12Device->CreateCommandQueue, I can't come up with a syntax that my compiler accept.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how to do it, I will post sample here if it could help someone else.

First, don't be idiot like me and don't forget to pin_ptr your native object's pointer otherwise GC will take care of them and it's getting harder to debug :)

Traditional resource creation in DX 12 :

```
pin_ptr<ID3D12CommandQueue*> pCmdQueue = &_commandQueue;
_d3d12Device->CreateCommandQueue(&queueDesc, __uuidof(**(&_commandQueue)), (void**)pCmdQueue);
```

QueryInterface in DX 12 :

```
pin_ptr<ID3D12DebugDevice1*> pDeviceDebug = &_d3d12DeviceDebug;
_d3d12Device->QueryInterface<ID3D12DebugDevice1>(pDeviceDebug);
```

Comment: You should not use `pin_ptr` with DirectX COM objects since they are not managed by GC. Use smart pointers targeting COM instead.

Comment: If I release everything correctly ? Is that a problem ? I am always do a live object report at the end of my app to ensure nothing is still live.

Comment: You should delegate releasing of objects to COM smart pointers. While `pin_ptr` should be only used to pin managed memory.

Comment: Thank for the advice, I will look at it.